# Sprinkles are seeding when scaling object in animation

Tags: animation, particles, physics, keyframes

i'm scaling the icing and all the sprinkles are changing positions at every frame.

I'm on the latest release as well (2.81).

Is there a way to solve this?

Here's the animation : 
[Sprinkles prank gone wrong!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFePt.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried hiding the emitter and using a separate icing object that is scaled (and visible)?

Comment: No. How do i do that?